# How to get `compile-goto-error` to find files mentioned in `npm run` script output (i.e., relative to `package.json` rather than cwd)?

Tags: compilation-mode

I develop an NPM package, and often use `M-x compile RET npm run test RET` and similar.  It is very convenient that `npm run` will search parent directories for a `package.json` file, and then execute the named script (in this case, `test`) from that directory: this means I can run this command while visiting any file in the project and relative pathnames in our build scripts will all work as expected.

Unfortunately, while emacs correctly parses most error messages that might appear in the `*Compilation*` buffer, clicking on an error message normally fails to find the file referenced, because the pathname shown is usually relative to a parent directories rather than the directory `compile` was invoked in.

I can modify `compilation-search-path` to add my package's top-level directory, but since I work with multiple repositories, some of which contain multiple independent NPM packages each with their own `package.json`, I would ideally like `compile-goto-error` to use the same algorithm that `npm run` does—i.e., evaluate the filename as relative to the enclosing directory containing `package.json`; failing that, I'd at least like it to try enclosing directories in turn if the filename cannot be found relative to the current directory.

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested.

You can try adding a `.dir-locals.el` file at the top level `npm` directory of your project and have it set `compilation-search-path` appropriately. See [Per-Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) in the Emacs manual.

E.g. suppose that your project is under `/path/to/project`, so the `package.json` file's path name is `/path/to/project/package.json`, then create a file `/path/to/project/.dir-locals.el` with the following contents:

```el
((nil . ((compilation-search-path . ("/path/to/project/")))))
```

Any file you open under the project directory (or its subdirectories) should have a local setting of `compilation-search-path` as above.

You will probably get the usual warning about unsafe local variables the first time you open a file in that directory. You might want to hit `!` to declare the variable as safe, thereby eliminating any future warnings about that variable. I think it's safe to do that with this variable.

Comment: Promising, but does not work: I end up with `compilation-search-path` as a buffer-local in every source file, but it remains non-local and set to `nil` in the `*compilation*` buffer, which is really the important part.  (I tried `(compilation-mode . ((compilation search path . (…))))))` but that seemed to have no effect at all.)

Comment: There goes that theory :-) I'll leave the non-answer up for a little bit and see if I can come up with something, but I can't think of anything ATM. If that continues, I'll delete it.

Comment: I don't have time to try it now, but it might be possible to pass the local value of `compilation-search-path` to `compile` by advising the latter, and let-binding compilation-search-path around the original call. Still untested of course, so caveat emptor. I'll try it out later and amend the answer if that works.

Comment: No, it's more complicated than that, I think...